# Find if an element in array has value equal to parent element value

Tags: c#, mongodb-query

Let's say we have a collection of documents like this one:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591c54faf1c1f419a830b9cf"),
    "fingerprint" : "3121733676",
    "screewidth" : "1920",
    "carts" : [ 
        {
            "cartid" : 391796,
            "status" : "New",
            "cart_created" : ISODate("2017-05-17T13:50:37.388Z"),
            "closed" : false,
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "brandid" : "PIR",
                    "cai" : "2259700"
                }
            ],
            "updatedon" : ISODate("2017-05-17T13:51:24.252Z")
        }, 
        {
            "cartid" : 422907,
            "status" : "New",
            "cart_created" : ISODate("2017-10-23T08:57:06.846Z"),
            "closed" : false,
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "brandid" : "PIR",
                    "cai" : "IrHlNdGtLfBoTlKsJaRySnM195U"
                }
            ],
            "updatedon" : ISODate("2017-10-23T09:46:08.579Z")
        }
    ],
    "createdon" : ISODate("2016-11-08T10:29:55.120Z"),
    "updatedon" : ISODate("2017-10-23T09:46:29.486Z")
}
```

How do you extract only the documents where no item in the array $.carts have $.carts.closed set to true and `$.carts.updatedon` greater than `$.updatedon` minus 3 days ?

I know how to do find all the documents where no item in the array satisfy the condition `$and: [closed: {$eq: true}, {updatedon: {$gt : new ISODate("2017-10-20T20:15:31Z")}}]`

But how can you reference the parent element `$.updatedon` for the comparison?

In plain mongodb shell query language it would aleady be of help.

But I am actually accessing it using c# driver, so my query filter is like this:

```
FilterDefinition<_visitorData> filter;
filter = Builders<_visitorData>.Filter
  .Gte(f => f.updatedon, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15));
filter = filter & (
  Builders<_visitorData>.Filter
    .Exists(f => f.carts, false) 
      | !Builders<_visitorData>.Filter.ElemMatch(f => 
        f.carts, c => c.closed && c.updatedon > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15)
      )
);
```

How can I replace `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15)` with a reference to the document root element `updatedon`?

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something but, if you use `f.updatedon` while comparing `c.updatedon` doesn't that work?

Comment: @VivekAthalye nope, because f is not available on the right side of ElemMatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can project the difference of carts.updatedon and updatedon and then filter out the results from this aggregation pipeline.

```
coll.aggregate([{'$unwind':'$carts'},
                {'$match':{'closed':{'$ne':true}}},
                {'$project':{'carts.cartid':1,'carts.status':1,'carts.cart_created':1,'carts.closed':1,'carts.items':1,'carts.updatedon':1,'updatedon':1,'diff':{'$subtract':['$carts.updatedon','$createdon']}}},
                {'$match': {'diff': {'$gte': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * days}}}])
```

days = 3 will filter out results more than 3 days difference documents.

I have just given the example of how you can use $subtract to find date difference and filter documents based on that.

Answer (score 1):

well I was in a similar situation few days back.
I tackled it by using Jobject of  Newtonsoft.Json.
Create a function to return bool which actually process each document take it as input.

```
  Jobject jOb=Jobject.parse(<Your document string>);
  JArray jAr=JArray.Parse(jOb["carts"]);
  If(jOb["updateon"]=<Your Business Validation>)
  {
     foreach(var item in jAr)
       if(item["closed"]==<Your validation>){ return true}         

   }
 return false;
```

I hope this helps :) 
If you handling with any null values in those properties then please use Tryparse and out variable.